# Torch argmax() returns different results for tensor on Mac MPS and CPU

Tags: pytorch, gpu, argmax

Torch argmax() returns correct results for tensor on CPU, but incorrect on MPS.

I have a matrix called `target_mixtures`, where `print(target_mixtures[0])` would give

```
tensor([0.0010, 0.6827, 0.0010, 0.0261, 0.0010, 0.0010, 0.0010, 0.0010, 0.0010, 0.0010, 0.0010, 0.0010, 0.0010, 0.0010, 0.2744, 0.0010, 0.0010, 0.0010, 0.0010, 0.0010], device='mps:0')
```

When I run `print(torch.argmax(target_mixtures[0].cpu()))`, it gives `1` as expected (the 0.6827 is largest).

However, when I run `print(torch.argmax(target_mixtures[0]))`, it gives `0`. Not having it on cpu (so on Mac MPS), it gives 0 for all these `target_mixtures[i]`.

I also attach a screenshot of my jupyter notebook, where these are just the 3 consecutive cells executed.

[The actual code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7fvV.png)